# Rootin' Tootin' Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> Its suffix sounds like a slithering snake.
>
> Its prefix is given again in green grass.
>
> Its infix appears as an arbitrary article.
>
> Its whole rhymes with whence it does pass.

It's a ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> GAS.

*Its suffix sounds like a slithering snake.*

> Sss.

*Its prefix is given again in green grass.*

> G.

*Its infix appears as an arbitrary article.*

> A, the indefinite article.

*Its whole rhymes with whence it does pass.*

> Gas can pass from one's arse/ass.

Comment: That last spoiler; the spoiler of the day.

Comment: @Stevo Blame the OP, not me :-)

Comment: Im going to 'flag' this question as rude or abusive... _totally_.